# How to connect SQL Server 2014 via Static IP?

Tags: networking, router, sql-server

This question might be duplicate but I read a lot of questions present on internet but still can't get a solution.
I have successfully created the connection of my server. But I am facing problems with client PC Server.
I have successfully followed the steps shown in this link.[connecting-from-another-computer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/lesson-2-connecting-from-another-computer?view=sql-server-ver15)
I am able to connect 2 client PC via Router and I can connect it in LAN via local IP like `tcp:192.168.0.5,49172\MSSQLEXPRESS` where 192.168.0.5 is local IP of the PC containing SQL-server.

Now I want to connect the server via static IP. I created a virtual server in the router with a specific port.

What I did:

- Client using windows 7 so I changed the connection to the home network
- Tried disabling anti-virus (thought it might have blocked the connection).
- Try changing ports.
- Restart PC, Restart Server, Reboot Router, etc.
- Allowed port in windows firewall.

Nothing working for my Client. The same process worked for me. 
The database is connected locally (even work with local IP as said above) but not via static or public IP.

Some more information: 
Client Router is Binatone WR3005N3 and Quick Heal Anti-Virus and my router is DLink DIR600M

EDIT: I brought my client pc to my office (where I have DLink Router) and tried to connect with my router (dlink) and it connects properly.
So I guess its a problem with the router.

Actually SQL server connects without any router configuration but still, I created some virtual servers and other things.
This image shows the local IP of client pc.
[image: IMAGE SHOWS LOCAL IP OF THE CLIENT PC.]

I created a virtual server in the router which points to the client's pc 

[image: Virtual Server]

I tried to connect via public IP but unable to connect SQL server.

[image: Tried for connection.]

The same PC when connected to my DLink router (brought Client pc at my office), it works fine.

Comment: If you run telnet 192.168.0.5 49172 does it say anything?

Comment: And How I check that it says anything? @SQLTemp

Comment: If I am connected to that router then yes, it connected with 192.168.0.105,49172.. @SQLTemp

Comment: You've tagged this as a sql-server issue, but I'd say this is an issue with your network, not SQL Server (assuming you followed the guide correctly). You haven't explained how the binatone and dlink are connected, or what their model are. You'd be better making another post where you go into detail on their configuration.

Comment: @pholcroft You are right but at first, I didn't know if the issue with SQL Server or Network.
I added a paragraph with the edit at the end. Moreover, Binatone and DLink are not connected. I just brought the client PC to my office. Also, I wrote in Some More Information that I have DLink and my CLient has Binatone Router. Ya, I didn't write the model Number and thats my mistake but I write it.

Comment: @pholcroft I edited the question. Please check the tags if I need any to remove or add. Any other suggestions will be helpful. :)

Comment: I understand, I am just trying to help you get an answer as I don't think that is possible with your current question and tagging. Good luck.

Comment: @pholcroft Thnx a lot for your efforts. What other tags do I add according to you?

Comment: I don't know, but I think you need to go to much more detail on how you have configured everything in each router. How else can people tell you if your configuration in the router is correct?

Comment: @pholcroft I updated the question again. 
Is there anything I need to add. This what all I did.

Comment: @SQLTemp Na it won't connect. Please see the question again. I updated it. I also learned about telnet.. :)

Comment: @bonny your internal port on your router should be 49172

Comment: @SQLTemp I am sorry about 49172 I mistyped it above.. The client PC has 2772 port in IPALL. I personally set it that some days ago.

Comment: @SQLTemp I have a doubt that the router firewall is blocking it. But I don't know where to shut the router firewall in this model. Also, there is less help with this router on the internet. Where can I ask router specific questions in StackExchange sites? Is SuperUser a proper site?

Comment: @bonny just had a quick look and I couldn’t see any firewall options on google ( not saying there isn’t any ) you can try use the dmz mode though and see how that goes

Comment: @SQLTemp It seems that the router has the problem. The customer agreed to change the router. I'll update here if anything new happens.